# Unbuffered output from tornado using wsgi

Tags: streaming, tornado, wsgi

I have created small django project to serve music. Everything is going through django, even the streaming part (the project is really small, 2-3 users maximum).

I now want to make the project self-contained so I am using tornado as the webserver. I am using something like the following:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
wsgi_app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(
    django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())

tornado_app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/static/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': STATIC_DIR}),
    (r'.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_app)),
])
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado_app)                                                                                                      
server.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Tornado though seems to buffer output and as a result streaming music is not possible. Is there any way to change this behavior? Or is there another webserver in python that could both serve the wsgi application and the static files?

EDIT: After some research, I have concluded that the problem most probably lies in `WSGIContainer`. It seems that in [the definition of `WSGIContainer`](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/9df23246564a8c8f53904fcf02f84000c9eeec77/tornado/wsgi.py#L233) the response is read into a buffer and then written to the client. So instead of rolling my own `WSGIContainer` based on the original, is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/issues/301), it seems that tornado is not the suitable server for what I need. I am probably going to use CherryPy which works out of the box.